# Flutter How to update data in real time?

Tags: flutter, real-time-updates

I am using rest apis for getting data but i want to update it in real time, I can't use firebase for the same. please suggest me any better way also calling api again and again is not good idea to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

For real time you need to use a real time database with a sdk for subscribe to it (like Firebase) or you can use socket.io to stream your data from a standard backend, socket.io is a library to abstract the WebSocket connections.

If you use node for backend i suggest you to read this topic on Nestjs https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways